# Показать названия переменных вместо их значения в ttk.Combobox?

Tags: python, python-2.x, tkinter, python-2.7

Импортирую список переменных из модуля tableofElements. В случае использования виджета Combobox вместо названия переменной отображается её значение. Если указать переменные в valueChosen в кавычках ("A", "B", ...), то в консоли выводятся буквы.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from tableofElements import *

win = tk.Tk()            
win.title("Elements")    


# values (A - DDDDDD)
ttk.Label(win, text="Element").grid(column=0, row=2)

value = tk.StringVar()
valueChosen = ttk.Combobox(win, width=12, textvariable=value, state='readonly')

# ВМЕСТО НАЗВАНИЯ ПЕРЕМЕННЫХ В ДАННОМ СЛУЧАЕ ОТОБРАЖАЮТСЯ ИХ ЗНАЧЕНИЯ
valueChosen['values'] = (A, B, C, D, E, AAA, BBB, CCC)

valueChosen.grid(column=0, row=3)
valueChosen.current(0)

# labels (inside)
aLabel = ttk.Label(win, text="A - DDDDDD")                  
aLabel.grid(column=1, row=3)

# button "OK - Sent"
def clickMe():                                               
    action.configure(text="Sent" + ' ' + valueChosen.get())
    aLabel.configure(foreground='red')
    print valueChosen.get() # ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ОТОБРАЖАЕТСЯ В КОНСОЛИ

action = ttk.Button(win, text="OK", command=clickMe)  
action.grid(column=2, row=3) 
action.focus()

win.mainloop()
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае можно добавлять в комбобокс имена переменных в кавычках:

```
valueChosen['values'] = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC')
```

Метод `.get()` комбобокса будет возвращать выбранное имя. Т.к. все переменные загружены при помощи `import` в глобальное пространство имен, то их значения можно получить с помощью словаря, возвращаемого функцией `globals()`:

```
def clickMe():
    v = globals()[valueChosen.get()]
    action.configure(text="Sent" + ' ' + v)
    aLabel.configure(foreground='red')
    print v # ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ ОТОБРАЖАЕТСЯ В КОНСОЛИ
```

Но я бы делал немного по-другому: в модуле `tableofElements` хранил бы не набор глобальных переменных, а словарь:

```
elements = dict(A=12, B=43, C=34, D=44, E=33, AAA=9340, BBB=2345, CCC=345)
```

В основной модуль импортировал только этот словарь, а потом ключи словаря (бывшие имена переменных) добавлял в `valueChosen['values']` (тогда не нужно будет вручную прописывать конкретные имена), а по нажатию кнопки выводил значение, соответствующее выбранному имени. Код примерно такой:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from tableofElements import elements

...

valueChosen['values'] = tuple(elements.keys())

...

def clickMe():
    v = elements[valueChosen.get()]
    action.configure(text="Sent" + ' ' + str(v))  # Приведение к строке нужно только если в словаре elements есть значения, не являющиеся строками
    aLabel.configure(foreground='red')
    print v # Значение отображается в консоли

...
```

**Обновление**

Вариация на тему первого варианта с автоматическим добавлением всех переменных модуля `tableofElements` (кроме служебных) в combobox (но без добавления их в глобальную область видимости):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tableofElements

...

# Добавление в combobox всех имен переменных из модуля tableofElements (кроме служебных)
valueChosen['values'] = tuple(name for name in dir(tableofElements) if not name.startswith('_'))

...

def clickMe():
    v = getattr(tableofElements, valueChosen.get())
    action.configure(text="Sent" + ' ' + str(v))
    aLabel.configure(foreground='red')
    print v # Значение отображается в консоли

...
```